# Cannot run Sqlectron

Tags: software-installation, mysql, deb, database, sql

I have installed  sqlectron v1.28.0 from the `.deb` file available [here](https://github.com/sqlectron/sqlectron-gui/releases/tag/v1.28.0)

but I cannot run it. The icon appears in my system. When I click on it nothing happens. I'm running 14.04 btw. Please help.

Comment: What's the output if you try to launch it from Terminal?

Comment: nothing happens. Its as if its not clickable at all. If I right click it expands only to show the uninstall button @SurvivalMachine

Answer (score 8):

if you try to launch it from Terminal, you will notice an error like this

> sqlectron: error while loading shared libraries: libgconf-2.so.4:
>   cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

which means you have to install the `libgconf`.

```
sudo apt-get install libgconf-2-4
```

Comment: That did it!
 OP should accept this answer.